# "I put a fix for this in develop" - now did he do that?

Tags: tense

My Scottish colleague chatted: "I put a fix for this in develop". I was wondering if he was still doing that, or if he already did that (I'm Dutch). Is he right? By the way, "develop" is a noun here. The chat went:

```
**Guy·Dec-18 2:11 PM**
I put a fix for this in develop

**Albert Hendriks·Dec-18 2:12 PM**
ok. Did you do that or will you do that?
"put" can be past tense or present tense :)

**Guy·Dec-18 2:13 PM**
i put a fix in already

**Albert Hendriks·Dec-18 2:13 PM**
ok, I''ll merge thanks

**Guy·Dec-18 2:14 PM**
'I will put a fix for this in develop' would be present tense
'I put something' would be past tense

**Albert Hendriks·Dec-18 2:15 PM**
ok :)
```

Comment: I don't like the edit. He literally said things like "'I put something' would be past tense", those are not comments that I added.

Comment: I rolled back the edit.

Comment: He's wrong, that's not the present tense, but I understand why. What do you think the present tense form of this sentence would mean?

Comment: @modulusshift I think "I put a fix for this in develop" would either be past tense, or it would be a slightly worse present tense way of saying "I'm putting a fix for this in develop".

Comment: You could also say "I create a fix for this in develop". That would be grammatically correct, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the present as shorthand for the present progressive. One of the reasons is that it leads to confusion between present and past tenses in sentences like this.

The present tense doesn't make any sense here, and so he must mean the past tense, and that the fix is already put in.

> I create a fix for this in develop.

Nope, that also doesn't work. Generally, the present tense can't be used by itself to describe a specific action. This doesn't work in Dutch either, does it?

Comment: In Dutch it would actually work, you would use the present tense when you haven't done it yet (Ik maak een fix hiervoor in develop, word-by-word translation "I create a fix for-this in develop") and the perfect tense when you've done it (Ik heb een fix hiervoor in develop gestopt: "I've put a fix for this in develop". This would be better in English as well, wouldn't it? (The result is important, that I can get his fix now)). In Dutch, you would never use the past tense here: "Ik maakte een fix hiervoor in develop" (I created/put a fix for this in develop).

Comment: Huh. That's odd. good to know. I didn't realize there were any significant differences in this sort of grammar across the Germanic languages.

Comment: I just asked my German speaking sister, and she told me the present progressive isn't that common and English is strange in this. :)

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but a native Dutch speaker wouldn't say that, unless someone asks "What did you do on Dec 18?" -Ik maakte een fix (hiervoor) in develop. But this is about the last part of my previous comment.

Comment: I'm somewhat amused that you have the logical pair to "therefore" in your language. "Wherefore?" "Therefore!" "No, herefore!" (I guess that means "for what reason?" "For that reason!" "No, for this reason!"?)

Comment: "for what reason?" "For that reason!" "No, for this reason!" would be "Waarom?" "Daarom!" "Nee, hierom!". If you are referring to "hiervoor", it would be "Waarvoor?", "Daarvoor!" "Nee. hiervoor!", which translates about the same and is used by native speakers as well, but is somewhat blunt. When you say "Waarom" ("why") you may be asking for a reason and/or indicating that you don't agree, whereas with "waarvoor" ("why") the tendency is somewhat  more towards not agreeing (this is my personal feeling). Now you say, "for what reason" may translate well to "waarvoor". and "why" to "waarom"

Comment: Cool. :) "therefore" is still used in English, "wherefore" is somewhat known from a Shakespeare line in Romeo and Juliet, but I don't know of a case of "herefore" in Modern English.

Answer (score 1):

Today I put a book on the shelf.

Yesterday I put a book on the shelf.

**Put** is a verb whose declension doesn't show any difference between present and past forms.

If we say in Dutch or German:

I make a fix request

it is understood to be future, in English, "I will make a fix request".

In German one could say "Morgen,  mache ich..."

Tomorrow, I (will) make...

In English, if we wanted to say that we're doing something now, or will be doing it in the very near future, we'd say:

I'm *putting* in a fix request.

I'm *making* a fix request.